# MongoDB - Convert collection to array field

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm newbie with mongodb. I have two collections, "season_16_17" and "teams". "teams" collection was created before season_16_17. Now i need to copy this teams collection as an array field of season_16_17.

teams:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("zzzzzzzz"),
        "club" : "Real Madrid",
        "name" : "Real Madrid A"        
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
        "club" : "At Madrid",
        "name" : "At Madrid A"
}
```

and now i need season_16_17 as :

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
        "teams":[
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("zzzzzzzz"),
        "club" : "Real Madrid",
        "name" : "Real Madrid A"        
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("xxxxxxx"),
        "club" : "R.S.D. ALCALA S.A.D.",
        "name" : "At Madrid A"
}]}
```

I've tried with:

```
db.teams.aggregate([{"$project":{"teams":"$$ROOT"}},{"$out":"season_16_17"}])
```

but the result isn't what i expected. This copy each team as an element of  season_16_17.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `$push` the values in an array, using a `$group` stage, where you group all elements by the same value, here using a new `ObjectId`, than `$out` to a new collection:

```
db.teams.aggregate([
    {$group: {_id: ObjectId(), teams: {$push: "$$ROOT"} }},
    {"$out":"season_16_17"}
]
)
```

Result:

```
db.season_16_17.find()


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("584a9f48dbaccc34c65b3055"),
    "teams" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("584a9f47dbaccc34c65b3053"),
            "club" : "Real Madrid",
            "name" : "Real Madrid A"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("584a9f47dbaccc34c65b3054"),
            "club" : "At Madrid",
            "name" : "At Madrid A"
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit:

`$out` will create a new collection.

At your suggestion, other solution is:

```
db.season_16_17.insert({"teams":db.teams.find().toArray()})
```

I worths mentioning that this second query might be slower, since there are 2 queries that are executed.

Comment: Great!! thanks @SergiuZaharie. I just found that i can do it also with `db.season_16_17.insert({"teams":db.teams.find().toArray()})` $out i think that will replace entire season_16_17 if i do it again, right? And what about if i want to import a csv file(for example) as a field of a collection.I cant see an option to import as a field, just as a collection. Is it possible? or you have to do it with javascript/coding. Is another question anyway. thanks!

Comment: Yes, $out will replace the whole collection.

Comment: Also, second query might be slower